# OrderBy and ThenBy combined with nested Where?

Tags: .net, linq

I have a list of objects that each contains a different list of other objects, like this:

```
Purchase (Date, Customer)
 - Item (Article No. , Price)
 - Item (Article No. , Price)
Purchase (Date, Customer)
 - Item (Article No. , Price)
 - Item (Article No. , Price)
```

I now want to run a query to find the purchase with the highest price for Item 1, in case several purchases with the same price exist, I want the latest one.

I've tried

```
   myList
    .OrderBy(p => p.Items
      .Where(i => i.ArticleNo == "numberImLookingFor")
      .Select(x => x.Price))
    .ThenBy(p => p.Date)
    .LastOrDefault()
```

but I receive an argument exception "at least one object must implement icomparable". I think this is because OrderBy implements some kind of lazy sorting and the nested where clause gets in the way.

How can I achieve the desired result with Linq?

Comment: @Rawling yeah fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `...Descending` and `Max`:

```
var mostExpensivePurchase =  purchaseList
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Items
        .Where(pItem => pItem.ArticleNo == "numberImLookingFor")
        .Max(pItem => pItem.Price))
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.Date)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```